# How do you factor $2ab-6ac-15c^2+5bc$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

$$2ab-6ac-15c^2+5bc$$

Here is what I have done:

$$(2ab-6ac)-(15c^2+5bc)$$
$$2a(b-3c)-5c(3c+b)$$
$$2a(b-3c)+5c(-3c-b)$$
$$2a(b-3c)+5c(-b-3c)$$
$$(b-3c)(2a-5c)$$

I know this isn't the correct answer but I can't figure out what I did wrong. Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Take a look at your second line.  If you distribute the $-5c$, you get:
$$
-5c(3c+b)=-15c^2-5bc
$$
which is not what you started with. You should have written $+5c(-3c+b)$.

Comment: Dear Daniel: We encourage users to "accept" helpful answers. You can accept one answer per question. To accept an answer, click on the $\large \checkmark$ located to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. You get two reputation points for each accepted answer! (You can also upvote as many answers as you'd like!)

Answer (score 2):

It should be  $(2ab−6ac)−(15c^2-5bc)$ at the first line you have done.

Answer (score 2):

Distributing your second line would give $2ab-6ac-15c^2-5bc,$ which is obviously not correct. Instead, it should be $+5c(-3c+b).$ Also observe that your last line should be $(2a+5c)$ instead of $(2a-5c)$ which would give you $(2a+5c)(b-3c).$